# Nested property not found in a Spring Data query method declaration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to use *findBy...* in my repository to get a Savingaccount object passing a nested attribute(name) as a parameter. Currently I'm using:

```
Mono<SavingAccount> findByOwnerName(String name);
```

but I'm getting this error: *No property name found for type Owner! Traversed path: SavingAccount.owner.*

My repository:

```
package com...SavingAccMS.Repository;

import com.everis.SavingAccMS.Model.Owner;
import com.everis.SavingAccMS.Model.SavingAccount;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public interface SavingAccountRepo extends ReactiveMongoRepository<SavingAccount, String>
{

   Mono<SavingAccount> findByNumber(String number);

   //This one is the problem
   Mono<SavingAccount> findByOwnerName(String name);

   Mono<SavingAccount> findByOwner(Owner owner);
}
```

My Entity:

```
package com...SavingAccMS.Model;

import java.security.acl.Owner;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Document(collection = "SavingAccs")
public class SavingAccount
{
   @Id
   private String id;

   @NotBlank
   private String number;

   @NotBlank
   private Owner owner;

   @NotBlank
   private String currency;

   @NotBlank
   private double balance = 0.00;

   @NotBlank
   private String status;
}
```

```
package com...SavingAccMS.Model;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Document(collection = "Owners")
public class Owner
{
   public String dni;

   public String name; //findBy this attribute is required.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your imports, the `Owner` in your `SavingAccount` refers to `java.security.acl.Owner`, not the one you defined yourself in `om...SavingAccMS.Model.Owner`. The former does not carry a `name` attribute.

Comment: Omg this is so embarrasing! Yep it works, I made too many changes I didn't noticed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

I'm not certain but I don't think you can find the owner name in hibernate like that.
I would try the following!

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM SavingAccount where owner.name = :name")
Mono<SavingAccount> findByOwnerName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Comment: Can you look the question again. He was using mongo db.

Comment: Thanks! It allows me to start the service but it's not a mongodb query. I'm still trying to use query methods